# how to get in java value of a cookie that was created in javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, cookies

I created a cookie in javascript, but when I try to get the value in java I get the previous value - the cookies hasn't refresh. is there any way to refresh the cookies so that I will get the correct value?
that is the javascript:

```
<script>
    function setCookie(name,value,days) { 
         if (days) {    
            var date = new Date();     
            date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));   
            var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
         }   
          else  {
          var expires = "";
          }
          document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
          alert (value);
    }
    function getCookie(c_name)
        {
        var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
        for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
          {
          x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
          y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
          x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
          if (x==c_name)
            {
            return unescape(y);
            }
          }
    }
    function del_cookie(name) {
    document.cookie = name +
    '=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;';
    }

  $j(document).ready(function(){
      // remove all click-events from header_nav_submenu 
        $j(".header_nav_submenu").unbind('click');  
        $j(".header_nav_submenu").click(function(){
        var goHref = $j(this).attr('href'); 
        del_cookie("last_page_nav");
        alert(getCookie("last_page_nav"));
        setCookie("last_page_nav", goHref.substring(7), 7); 
        alert(getCookie("last_page_nav"));
    });
});
</script>
```

and that is how I try to get the value from the cookie in java:

```
if(FriendlyURLUtil.getFriendlyURL(request.getServerName())==null){
            Cookie[] cookies =  ((HttpServletRequest) request).getCookies();
            for(int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) { 
                if (cookies[i].getName().equals("last_page_nav")) {
                    System.out.println("The days " + cookies[i].getMaxAge());
                    System.out.println("The cookie says " + cookies[i].getValue());
                    ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(cookies[i].getValue());
                }
            } 

        }
```

Comment: I am trying to understand the flow here. First your client gets a response (page) from the server. The client then runs some javascript to change the cookies stored on the client. When the client requests the next page from the server it does not send the new modified cookie, but rather the old original cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Your cookie was expired at  01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT, i.e. January, 1, 70 AC, i.e. 1940 years ago. This is the reason that server side does not receive it. Check the way you create expiration date.

Comment: the cookie is only expired if del_cookie is called. Standard deletion script.

Answer (score 0):

delete the old cookies

> document.cookie = ckName + "=" + "; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01
>   GMT";
>
> if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
>   c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(ckName + "=");
>
> if (c_start != -1) {
>   c_start = c_start + ckName.length + 1;
>   c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
>   if (c_end == -1)
>   c_end = document.cookie.length;
>   return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
>   }
>   }

you can get cookies from HttpServletRequest

> Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

if you want all the cookie name and value, iterate the array

> for (int index = 0; index < cookies.length; index++) {  ckName =
>   cookies[index].getName();  ckValue = cookies[index].getValue();  }